# Plot frequency of contact id in channel for a Pandas DF

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

This is my Pandas DF structure:

```
    Id                  channel     
0   0140268216898719    RIA          
2   022427195461267     Wire         
3   023552004060340     Ind
```

With more columns that are not important, and more data.

I am looking to plot a histogram using seaborn to show frequency of contactId for each channel, however I am failing miserably not matter what I try.

The way I see it, I can either group Id by channel and have a bar plot (attempted as follows):

```
df=df['channel'].groupby(['Id']).count() #count occurrences of Id for each channel
```

Results in:

```
channel
Ind            174
RIA             60
Wire            77
```

And

```
tips = sns.load_dataset("df")
ax = sns.barplot(x="channel", y="Id", data=tips)
```

HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found

or a histogram of channel vs. frequency of Id, something like the below:

```
sns.distplot(df, kde=False, rug=True)
```

Here I get a plot with Id on x axis and frequency between 0 to 2 on y axis.

In other words neither of these options provide the output I need.

Can anyone give me a hand to properly plot the initially given data? Thank you!

Comment: `df.groupby(['Id'])['channel'].count()`

Comment: The comment above probably solves the conundrum but what errors did you receive?

Comment: @Q.Holness updated

Comment: the following link will help. http://www.scipy-lectures.org/packages/statistics/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was doing `tips = sns.load_dataset("df")` as per the documentation, but this is nothing more than a Seaborn way of pulling data from csv on their server.
Simply stating `data=df` inside `barplot()` extracts data from my DF.. The apply function I added is for unique counts instead of just count.

```
df=df.groupby(['channel'])['Id'].apply(lambda x:len(x.unique())).reset_index()
print(df)
sns.set(style='darkgrid')
sns.barplot(x='channel', y='Id', data=df, palette='Set2')
plt.show()
```

--Edit
to order by count desc, I suggest doing something like this:

```
result = df.sort_values('Id',ascending=False)
sns.barplot(x='channel', y='id', data=result, palette='Set2')
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation together with your code. Otherwise you risk having your answer flagged for deletion.